# Can not set the origin to a hierarchy/group

Tags: mesh, snapping, groups, outliner, origin

Whenever I Select my Group/null/Hierarchy under the outliner. I can't seem to make the origin to geometry work. It stuck in (0,0,0). I've tried to set the cursor to the middle of the group/hierarchy and snap to cursor but that only moves my group of objects away and sets the origin where my group was. I've tried selection to curser (Keep Offset) but that also doesn't work. Lost :( This is so simple why is it that I cant make it work. here is a picture of the issue. This might be so simple but I've tried everything.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe try either 'Origin to Center of Mass' (Both types, I don't know what the difference is) or 'Origin to Cursor' then 'Geometry to Origin'.

Comment: You'd have to select all the children to get _all_ of their origins to go to their respective geometries?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys!! Aw man. That would take forever. In Maya you could just select the entire group and move it wherever. Is there possibly a way to convert the hierarchy to something more efficient.

Comment: I've tried the advice doesn't work.